# Microsoft Graph API get calendar changes in a time interval, filter by lastModifiedDateTime

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

**Im trying to get the modified or created events in the calendar, after a specific date.**

1. Following [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), i can use this url to get the events of this year.

> `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2020-01-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2021-01-01T00:00:00`

2. Since i want to get only the modified or created events after a specific date im trying to use filter and lastModifiedDateTime attibute, by this way

> `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2020-01-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2021-01-01T00:00:00&$filter=lastModifiedDateTime%20gt%202020-10-01T00:00:00z`

trying to get the events which were modified this month, i get a empty response, not even errors.

3. I also tried this way [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-events?tabs=http) using

> `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView/delta?startDateTime=2020-01-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2021-01-01T00:00:00&lastModifiedDateTime%20gt%202020-10-01T00:00:00z`

but it returns all the events of the year and does not filter by lastModifiedDateTime.

**There are any proper way to get the modified or created calendar events after a specific date?**

Comment: I remember looking documentation of delta beta endpoint, mentioning $filter is not supported. Here's the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delta?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http. Being said that, if you wish Microsoft to consider implement a new feature to address the above, then you can file an uservoice here: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like calendarView does not work properly with filter, a working alternative is filter list events, [Documentation Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

A working url looks like this : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime%20gt%20" + date + "z"`